# Android duplicates activity when minimized, then maximized

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have google searched this with no success and seams very strange to me.

I am building a simple GPS app that send co-ordinates with HttpRequest, though I have noticed when minimising the UI then maximising, It runs a duplicate of the same activity. and doubles up on HttpRequest's

```
private LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);
    processExtraData();

}


private void processExtraData() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            10000, 5, this);
}


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String driver_id = extras.getString("driverid");

        String msg = "Driver:" + driver_id + "\nCurrent Location:\nLatitude: " + location.getLatitude()
                + "\nLongitude: " + location.getLongitude();

        new HttpRequestTask(
                new HttpRequest("https://www.autoflora.net/driver/gps.php?user_id=" + driver_id + "&latlong=" + location.getLatitude() + "*" + location.getLongitude(), HttpRequest.POST, "{ \"some\": \"data\" }"),
                new HttpRequest.Handler() {
                    @Override
                    public void response(HttpResponse response) {
                        if (response.code == 200) {
                            Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), "Request successful!");
                        } else {
                            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Request unsuccessful: " + response);
                        }
                    }
                }).execute();
        String s = calc.getText().toString();
        calc.setText(s + "1")

        TextView driver = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.driver);
        driver.setText("" + driver_id);

        TextView Longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);

        // Getting reference to TextView tv_latitude
        TextView Latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude);

        // Setting Current Longitude
        Longitude.setText("Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());

        // Setting Current Latitude
        Latitude.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude());

        //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: After further investigation, i believe that it is either the requestLocationUpdates() or the HttpRequestTask() that duplicates it's self... Any solutions? –

Comment: What do you mean by "minimizing then maximizing"? What specific buttons do you tap?

Comment: sorry.. that should have been updated. when the app is in focus or not

Comment: again, you should describe the exact actions you take that cause the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> noticed when minimising the UI then maximising

There's neither `minimising` nor `maximizing` of UI on Android. You apparently start the activity again via launcher (this is most likely your `maximizing` thing) which creates new instance of you activity. If you want just single instance allowed no matter what, you must set system so by using `android:launchMode` in declaration of activity in your manifest file. See [docs here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) for possible options.

Comment: Thanks for your input Marcin, unfortunately it has n ot worked. I have tried all launchmode's as well as intent.setFlags() also with not success. I did notice there was some differences when changing the launch modes, but still, the 2nd activity always creates a new one unless i manually close the whole app

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "start", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "resume", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        locationcheck(); // checks permissions
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "pause", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
     //   locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "stop", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "destroy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        finish();

    }
```

Seems to have fixed it..